How can I track which specific product each user viewed in Marketing Cloud Personalization?
I've set up site mapping in Marketing Cloud Personalization to capture user details when they view a product on our site. Currently, I'm receiving user records in MCP, but I need to track which specific product each user viewed. Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

You can refer the below document to capture the product for each user viewed. You need to set the interaction for the same. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/sitemapping-getting-started.html
interaction: {
name: SalesforceInteractions.CatalogObjectInteractionName.ViewCatalogObject,
catalogObject: {
    type: "Product",
    id: () => {
        return SalesforceInteractions.util.resolveWhenTrue.bind(() => {
            const productId = SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(".product-id").first().text();
            const products = getProductsFromDataLayer();
            if (products && products.length > 0) {
                return products[0].id;
            } else if (productId) {
                return productId;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
    },
    attributes: {
        sku: { id: SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(".product-detail[data-pid]").attr("data-pid") },
        name: SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromJsonLd("name"),
        description: SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromSelector(".short-description", (desc) => desc.trim()),
        url: SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromHref(),
        imageUrl: SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromSelectorAttribute(".product-carousel .carousel-item[data-slick-index='0'] img", "src", (url) => window.location.origin + url),
        inventoryCount: 1,
        price: SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromSelector(".prices .price .value", (price) => parseFloat(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""))),
        rating: () => {
            return SalesforceInteractions.mcis.extractFirstGroup(/([.\w]+) out of/, SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(".ratings .sr-only").text());
        },
    },
    relatedCatalogObjects: {
        Category: SalesforceInteractions.DisplayUtils.pageElementLoaded(".container .product-breadcrumb .breadcrumb a", "html").then((ele) => {
            return SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.buildCategoryId(".container .product-breadcrumb .breadcrumb a", null, null, (categoryId) => [categoryId.toUpperCase()]);
        }),
        Gender: SalesforceInteractions.DisplayUtils.pageElementLoaded(".product-breadcrumb .breadcrumb a, h1.product-name", "html").then((ele) => {
            if (SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(".product-breadcrumb .breadcrumb a").first().text().toLowerCase() === "women" ||
                SalesforceInteractions.cashDom("h1.product-name").text().indexOf("Women") >= 0) {
                return ["WOMEN"];
            } else if (SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(".product-breadcrumb .breadcrumb a").first().text().toLowerCase() === "men" ||
                SalesforceInteractions.cashDom("h1.product-name").text().indexOf("Men") >= 0) {
                return ["MEN"];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }),
        Color: SalesforceInteractions.DisplayUtils.pageElementLoaded(".attributes", "html").then((ele) => {
            return SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromSelectorAttributeMultiple(".color-value", "data-attr-value");
        }),
        Feature: SalesforceInteractions.DisplayUtils.pageElementLoaded(".features", "html").then((ele) => {
            return SalesforceInteractions.resolvers.fromSelectorMultiple(".long-description li", (features) => {
                return features.map((feature) => {
                    return feature.trim().toUpperCase();
                })
            })
        })
    }
}

}
